# Finding values within broadcast variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, broadcast

I want to join two sets by applying broadcast variable. I am trying to implement the first suggestion from [Spark: what's the best strategy for joining a 2-tuple-key RDD with single-key RDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621596/spark-whats-the-best-strategy-for-joining-a-2-tuple-key-rdd-with-single-key-rd)

```
val emp_newBC = sc.broadcast(emp_new.collectAsMap())
val joined = emp.mapPartitions({ iter =>
      val m = emp_newBC.value
      for {
        ((t, w)) <- iter
        if m.contains(t)
      } yield ((w + '-' + m.get(t).get),1)
    }, preservesPartitioning = true)
```

However as mentioned here: [broadcast variable fails to take all data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691591/broadcast-variable-fails-to-take-all-data) I need to use collect() rather than collectAsMAp(). I tried to adjust my code as below:

```
val emp_newBC = sc.broadcast(emp_new.collect())
val joined = emp.mapPartitions({ iter =>
      val m = emp_newBC.value
      for {
        ((t, w)) <- iter
        if m.contains(t)
        amk = m.indexOf(t)
      } yield ((w + '-' + emp_newBC.value(amk)),1) //yield ((t, w), (m.get(t).get))   //((w + '-' + m.get(t).get),1)
    }, preservesPartitioning = true)
```

But it seems m.contains(t) does not respond. How can I remedy this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
val emp_newBC = sc.broadcast(emp_new.groupByKey.collectAsMap)

val joined = emp.mapPartitions(iter => for {
  (k, v1) <- iter
  v2 <- emp_newBC.value.getOrElse(k, Iterable())
} yield (s"$v1-$v2", 1))
```

Regarding your code... As far as I understand `emp_new` is a `RDD[(String, String)]`. When it is collected you get an `Array[(String, String)]`. When you use

```
((t, w)) <- iter
```

`t` is a `String` so `m.contains(t)` will always return `false`.

Another problem I see is `preservesPartitioning = true` inside `mapPartitions`. There a few possible scenarios:

1. `emp` is partitioned and you want `joined` to be partitioned as well. Since you change key from `t` to some new value partitioning cannot be preserved and resulting `RDD` has to be repartitioned. If you use `preservesPartitioning = true` output `RDD` will end up with wrong partitions.
2. `emp` is partitioned but you don't need partitioning for `joined`. There is no reason to use `preservesPartitioning`.
3. `emp` is not partitioned.  Setting `preservesPartitioning` has no effect.

Comment: val emp_newBC = sc.broadcast(emp_new.groupByKey.collectAsMap) part still returns missing data. I try with a small dataset and i anticipate 354 rows in my broadcast variable but it returns 312 rows. I think the reason is still valid as stated in the 2nd link i wrote on my post. Isn't it possible to work with only collect()? And yes emp has to be partitioned. Indeed emp has 500 partitions. I do not get it how to repartition new rdd. Shall i repartition joined?

Comment: It should cover all values. What do you get when you run `emp_newBC.value.values.map(_.size).sum`? Regarding partitioning do you have partitioner? What is the output from `emp.partitioner`?

Comment: To control the size i had checked it through `val oo = emp_newBC.value` and as a result it still showed less number. However when I run your code it works perfectly. Now I wonder if this would be a good approach. ..`joined.repartition(sc.defaultParallelism * 500)` Shall I again partition joined by 500 as it was at the beginning?

Comment: If you don't use partitioner there is nothing else to do here. Regarding broadcast map it's should work just fine and it is the only efficient solution here.

Comment: I get emp as val emp = sc.textFile("text.txt",500).map(line => (line.split("\t")(5),line.split("\t")(0))).distinct(). But emp.partitioner returns null. And when I monitor UI it do shows 500 partitions. I am a bit confused. If you dont mind i have another small question. Now spark spills and cannot finish the job since emp is too big. Increasing partition number (e.g. from 500 to 5000) has any effect on it?

Comment: Yes, increasing number of partitions should help.